# JAVA_HOME in Solaris sparcv9

Tags: java, solaris, java-7, solaris-10

I am trying to install a java based application on `Solaris 10 (Sparc)` which is requesting for the `JAVA_HOME` path. I noticed that the files in `JAVA_HOME` for Solaris Sparc varies from Solaris Intel. When I set the JDK install directory as `JAVA_HOME`, the application does not detect this to be a valid JAVA_HOME.

Have you noticed any similar behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can i know where is your java downloaded